# How to pass a variable from controller to javascript within a view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I have an array @fields which has text and an id, asset_id.
To pass local variables from controller to view in render we use

```
render(:template => "assets/invalid", :locals => {:asset_id => params[:id], :fields => @fields})
```

The view is

```
<div id="panel">
  <script>
    alert('Invalid values for ')
    window.location = "../assets/" 
  </script>
</div>
```

This should generate a popup box. However, I want the popup box to redirect to "../assets/asset_id" and also display 'Invalid values for + fields'

The following doesn't work,

```
<div id="panel">
  <script>
    var fields = fields
    var asset_id = asset_id 
    alert('Invalid values for ' + fields )
    window.location = "../assets/" + asset_id 
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: When you do rake routes do you see /assets/:id ?

Comment: Yes, I do see it. The alertbox redirects to ../assets/. I want it to redirect to ../assets/asset_id.

Comment: Post how you are getting the asset_id and how you want to send it.  Since its html.erb you can just grab it.

Comment: The assets_id is from the controller. I want to send it to the script in the view to create the location of that asset, i.e. redirect to that ID page. The :local within render should send it to the view, shouldn't it? The JS has to create that link for window.location to redirect to.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be as simple as this?

```
<div id="panel">
  <script>
    var fields = <%= fields.to_json %>
    var asset_id = <%= asset_id.to_json %>
    alert('Invalid values for ' + fields )
    window.location = "../assets/" + asset_id 
  </script>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** And by the way, why do you need to pass `fields` or `params` as a local variable, why not to use `@fields` in your view?

Comment: The .to_json method isn't working. The view (alert box) doesn't show up. If I kept it as just fields as @Viren said, the alert box says 'Invalid values for undefined'.

Comment: Check page source -- what it's being converted to

Comment: fields is an array of strings and asset_id is a string

Answer (score 1):

An approach I have used in a couple apps where it's necessary for the client code to use server data is to build a hash and render it into a json literal on the page and have all my JS reference that object. It's the same approach as mentioned above but it's a bit cleaner because you don't have to mix a lot of server tags into your JS code. Easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

What wrong with this

```
<div id="panel">
  <script>
    var fields = fields
    var asset_id = <%= asset_id %> 
    alert('Invalid values for ' + fields )
    window.location = "../assets/" + asset_id 
  </script>
</div>
```

Now you can pass data to html for advance thing you can use something like **gon** check out gon gem it might help

Comment: The `to_s` of an array is not consistently parseable as JS across Ruby versions. Though the `inspect` output of an array mostly is, it's safer to go with `to_json`.

Comment: @Phrogz Point very well Expected